# The Method getDrawGraphics() is undefined for type string and The Method show(int[]) is undefined for type string

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, pixel

I am following [TheChernoProjects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKbZECPjQs0) tutorials and I'm trying to draw pixels
to the screen. . . This is my code:

```
    private void Render() {

    BufferStrategy BufferSrat = this.getBufferStrategy();

    if (BufferStrat == null) {

        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;

    }

    Screen.Render();

    for (int i = 0; i < (WindowWidth * WindowHeight); i++) {

        Pixels[i] = Screen.Pixels[i];

    }

    Graphics GG = BufferStrat.getDrawGraphics();
    GG.drawImage(Image, 0, 0, WindowWidth, WindowHeight, null);
    GG.dispose();
    BufferStrat.show(Pixels);

}
```

and the errors are: 'The Method getDrawGraphics() is undefined for type string' and 'The Method show(int[]) is undefined for type string' I'm using eclipse luna and Java SE 1.7

Please help, Thanks!

Comment: sidenote: youre not using the correct naming conventions for java ( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html ). methods and variables should be camelcasing but starting with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a typo in your line `BufferStrategy BufferSrat = this.getBufferStrategy();`

it should be `BufferStrategy BufferStrat = this.getBufferStrategy();`

Comment: Thanks i should have check more thoroughly sorry to waste your time